# How can I refactor this code to not return null twice?

Tags: c#, exception, null, json.net, conditional-statements

I have this code that returns null if a bad result is encountered *and* in the case of an exception:

```
private JArray GetRESTData(string uri)
{
    try
    {
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        if ((webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) && (webResponse.ContentLength > 0))
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
            string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(s);
        }
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Status code == {0}", webResponse.StatusCode));
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

...but it smells a bit rancid. Is there a way I can refactor this to not call "return null" twice?

Comment: add final block and return null there and remove from both try and catch block

Comment: any reason you are not using "using block" for webResponse.GetResponseStream() which dispose the object say when you have a bad connection.

Comment: This code has way bigger problems than two `return null`s. It eats arbitrary exceptions, it mixes up error display code with business logic, it doesn't dispose its resources. Fix the large problems before you look at the trivia.

Comment: @EricLippert: I'm using Matthew's code below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you don't handle the exception within this function, assume it behaves correctly.

```
private JArray GetRESTData(string uri)
{
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

    var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
    string s = reader.ReadToEnd();

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(s);
}
```

I removed the `StatusCode` check because the `HttpWebResponse` class will already throw an exception if it's not a valid status code.

The responsibility of this method should be to get the rest data, not to deal with user interaction (the `MessageBox`).

To refactor this further, I would make another method to make the web-request, and another to parse the response.

```
private JArray GetRESTData(string uri)
{
    var json = ReadFromUri(uri);

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(json);
}

private string ReadFromUri(string uri)
{
    using (var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri))
    using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }   
}
```

To use this method:

```
try 
{
    var myArray = GetRESTData("http://someservice.com/bananabread");
} 
catch (WebException exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Some exception happened: {0}", exception);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just move the return out of the try/catch block

```
try
{
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
    if ((webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) && (webResponse.ContentLength > 0))
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(s);
    }
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Status code == {0}", webResponse.StatusCode));    
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

}
return null;
```

Answer (score 2):

I like prefer a single return point, *if possible*:

```
private JArray GetRESTData(string uri)
{
    JArray ret = null; // single return value, declared outside of try/catch
    try
    {
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        if ((webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) && (webResponse.ContentLength > 0))
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
            string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
            ret = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(s);
        }
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Status code == {0}", webResponse.StatusCode));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Note: in this simple example, this is probably enough.  In more complex functions, you might want to set `ret` to `null` within the exception handler if it has been constructed but in an invalid state.  If you're using RAII however, this shouldn't really be an issue.